# Display .ico or .icon image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image

I have an API providing images with .icon format and I would like to display the image on my Flutter app.

Comment: can you provide the link of one icon

Comment: Here is the link 
https://api.hala-on.com/category_images/icons/1672329105.icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use image widget for it like bellow

```
Image.asset("assets/images/home.ico"),
      Image.network(
          "https://api.hala-on.com/category_images/icons/1672329105.icon"),
```

i have write these two widgets of image in actions and see the results one is displaying the .ico image from the assets and the other is displaying the image from the link you provided.

**see the results**

[image]

**Code for this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Image.asset("lib/assets/logo/waum_logo.ico"),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.